# How to switch to real full screen on Android 2.2?

Tags: android, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

I found bunch of samples how to remove title/notification bar on Android. However, it's still not a full screen.

I still see a panel on my table with search, home, back and some other button.

Do you have any ideas how to hide this panel?

Generally speaking, I want kind of kiosk mode.

Comment: What device is this? Are you running a custom version of Android? Soft home/back/etc keys were not part of stock Android until 3.0 and applications are not permitted to make them unavailable to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem was device specific. I was doing development for Archos and Archos has it's own bar, which isn't not removed by FLAG_FULLSCREEN and FEATURE_NO_TITLE

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in onCreate of activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for a fullscreen activity:

```
public class HellofullActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

where you request that the window has not the green title bar and take full screen.

Comment: This doesn't work. It removes title, but it doesn't remove panel with home/search and etc buttons on the tablet.

Comment: Does your tablet is modded and have some kind of honeycomb style bar? in code you can remove only the upper bar with the clock and battery.

Comment: I think you are right. I looked on this a little bit more. The tablet is Archos 101 and it has as you pointed out honeycomb style bar.